# How to update particular field value on controller method ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have user model as follows

```
t.string   "name"
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "encrypted_password"
t.string   "salt"
t.string   "remember_token"
t.boolean  "admin"
t.boolean  "active"
```

I need to change the boolean value on **active** attribute. How can I do it on my method ?

Comment: @user.update_attribute(:active, true)

Answer (score 7):

You can do it this way

```
@user.active = true
@user.save
```

Or this way (on update actions)

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Or did you mean sth else?

Comment: If I use @user.save it doesn't save the values to database

Comment: But it should. I think the word active might be a problem to rails, may be a "bad word". Try to rename the column to currently_active. Then try it again.